# LWJGL Vertex data seems corrupted

Tags: java, opengl, buffer, rendering, lwjgl

I am trying to render a triangle to see how LWJGL works. Each frame, I reset the vertex data `ByteBuffer` and write 3 vertices to it directly. Then I call `buffer.flip()` to ready the data to be uploaded to the GPU and call `glBufferData(...)` and finally `glDrawArrays(...)`, but no triangle shows. Using the debug program RenderDoc I was able to look at the vertex data that was supposedly uploaded and it definitely doesn't seem right.

[image: RenderDoc vertex data result]

As you can see, each position is extremely small (like 41 zero's after the the `.`). I don't see any errors, even with the GLFW error callbacks and debug context set up.

> **All Java code:**

```java
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GLUtil;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MinimalExample {

    private static void debugPrintErrors() {
        System.out.println("-> DEBUG PRINT ERRORS");
        int error;
        while ((error = GL30.glGetError()) != GL30.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(" ");
            switch (error) {
                case GL30.GL_INVALID_ENUM                  -> b.append("INVALID_ENUM");
                case GL30.GL_INVALID_VALUE                 -> b.append("INVALID_VALUE");
                case GL30.GL_INVALID_OPERATION             -> b.append("INVALID_OP");
                case GL30.GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION -> b.append("INVALID_FB_OP");
            }

            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }

    private static String readResource(String res) {
        try {
            InputStream is = MinimalExample.class.getResourceAsStream(res);
            String s = new String(is.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            is.close();
            return s;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    // vertex data buffer
    private static final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4096);

    // shader program
    static int program;

    // render objects
    static int vao;
    static int vbo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // set buffer limit
        buf.limit(4096).position(0);

        // init glfw and create window
        GLFW.glfwInit();
        long window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "Hello", 0, 0);

        // create GL
        GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        GL.createCapabilities();
        GLUtil.setupDebugMessageCallback(System.out);
        GLFW.glfwSetErrorCallback(GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.out));

        // create vertex objects
        vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        vbo = GL30.glGenBuffers();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
        GL30.glBindBuffer(GL30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 7 * 4, 0);
        GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 7 * 4, 7 * 3);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        // compile and link shaders
        int vertexShader   = GL30.glCreateShader(GL30.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        int fragmentShader = GL30.glCreateShader(GL30.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        GL30.glShaderSource(vertexShader,   readResource("/test.vsh"));
        GL30.glShaderSource(fragmentShader, readResource("/test.fsh"));
        GL30.glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        GL30.glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
        program = GL30.glCreateProgram();
        GL30.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        GL30.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
        GL30.glLinkProgram(program);

        // render loop
        while (!GLFW.glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            // poll events
            GLFW.glfwPollEvents();

            // clear screen
            GL30.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            GL30.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            // render
            render();

            // swap buffers
            GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        }
    }

    static void render() {
        // put vertex data
        // manual to simulate graphics library
        putVec3(0.25f, 0.25f, 1f); putVec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        putVec3(0.75f, 0.25f, 1f); putVec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        putVec3(0.50f, 0.75f, 1f); putVec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        buf.flip();

        // bind program
        GL30.glUseProgram(program);

        // bind vertex array
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        // upload graphics data and draw
        GL30.glBindBuffer(GL30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        GL30.glBufferData(GL30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf, GL30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL30.glDrawArrays(GL30.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        // reset vertex data buffer
        buf.position(0);
        buf.limit(buf.capacity());
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////

    static void putVec3(float x, float y, float z) {
        buf.putFloat(x);
        buf.putFloat(y);
        buf.putFloat(z);
    }

    static void putVec4(float x, float y, float z, float w) {
        buf.putFloat(x);
        buf.putFloat(y);
        buf.putFloat(z);
        buf.putFloat(w);
    }

}
```

> **All shader code (merged into one block for convenience, actually two files in reality):**

```c
/*
   test.vsh
*/

#version 330 core

in layout(location = 0) vec3 position;
in layout(location = 1) vec4 col;

out layout(location = 0) vec4 fColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position * 1000, 1);
    fColor      = col;
}

/*
   test.fsh
*/

#version 330 core

in layout(location = 0) vec4 fColor;

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    outColor = fColor;
}
```

**Edit:** I know the contents of the `ByteBuffer` are correct, checking them each frame yields:

```
[ 0.25, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.75, 0.25, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, ]
```

Comment: The last parameter in `GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 7 * 4, 7 * 3);` should be `3*4` (an offset of the position: 12 bytes). Does this help?

Comment: It sort of fixed the structure of the color part, not really though the values are still ridiculous so it still isn't showing anything.

Comment: Yeah, I checked by duplicating the buffer, pulling floats and printing them. It looks right. This is after calling `.flip()`

Comment: Calling `buf.asFloatBuffer()` doesn't fix the issue, I'll try just using a `FloatBuffer` from the start, but I don't know if that will change anything because LWJGL just takes it as a pointer. Edit: Nope, using a float buffer actually causes the JVM to crash with an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`

Comment: Using a FloatBuffer should be possible, indicating that something is wrong here. Does [this example](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/master/modules/samples/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/opengl/GLXGears.java) or [this example](https://github.com/ra4king/LWJGL-OpenGL-Tutorials/blob/master/src/com/ra4king/opengl/test/Test.java) help?

Comment: No I think the problem is that a `FloatBuffer` can't be allocated directly meaning it can't derive a native memory pointer to the data, while with a `ByteBuffer` you have an `allocateDirect` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 problems.

The first problem is `buf`. `ByteBuffer::allocateDirect` allocates a **BIG_ENDIAN** buffer, but OpenGL is a C library, which is **LITTLE_ENDIAN**. So it must be allocated with `BufferUtils::createByteBuffer` or `MemoryUtil::memAlloc`.

The second problem is the offset of `glVertexAttribPointer`. It should be `4 * 3` for 3 floats.

The third problem is your vertex shader. The input position was multiplied by 1000, which is out of the viewport. To avoid this, you just have to remove the multiplication or use a projection matrix.

```c
gl_Position = vec4(position /* * 1000 */, 1);
```

BTW I recommend to use `ByteBuffer::clear` to reset the vertex data buffer, because it is a builtin method.

Fixed Java code:

```java
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GLUtil;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class MinimalExample {

    private static void debugPrintErrors() {
        System.out.println("-> DEBUG PRINT ERRORS");
        int error;
        while ((error = GL30.glGetError()) != GL30.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(" ");
            switch (error) {
                case GL30.GL_INVALID_ENUM                  -> b.append("INVALID_ENUM");
                case GL30.GL_INVALID_VALUE                 -> b.append("INVALID_VALUE");
                case GL30.GL_INVALID_OPERATION             -> b.append("INVALID_OP");
                case GL30.GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION -> b.append("INVALID_FB_OP");
            }

            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }

    private static String readResource(String res) {
        try {
            InputStream is = MinimalExample.class.getResourceAsStream(res);
            String s = new String(is.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            is.close();
            return s;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    // vertex data buffer
    private static final ByteBuffer buf = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(4096);

    // shader program
    static int program;

    // render objects
    static int vao;
    static int vbo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // set buffer limit
        buf.limit(4096).position(0);

        // init glfw and create window
        GLFW.glfwInit();
        long window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "Hello", 0, 0);

        // create GL
        GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        GL.createCapabilities();
        GLUtil.setupDebugMessageCallback(System.out);
        GLFW.glfwSetErrorCallback(GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.out));

        // create vertex objects
        vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        vbo = GL30.glGenBuffers();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
        GL30.glBindBuffer(GL30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 7 * 4, 0);
        GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL30.GL_FLOAT, false, 7 * 4, 4 * 3);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        // compile and link shaders
        int vertexShader   = GL30.glCreateShader(GL30.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        int fragmentShader = GL30.glCreateShader(GL30.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        GL30.glShaderSource(vertexShader,   readResource("/test.vsh"));
        GL30.glShaderSource(fragmentShader, readResource("/test.fsh"));
        GL30.glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        GL30.glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
        program = GL30.glCreateProgram();
        GL30.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        GL30.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
        GL30.glLinkProgram(program);

        // render loop
        while (!GLFW.glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            // poll events
            GLFW.glfwPollEvents();

            // clear screen
            GL30.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            GL30.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            // render
            render();

            // swap buffers
            GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        }
    }

    static void render() {
        // put vertex data
        // manual to simulate graphics library
        putVec3(0.25f, 0.25f, 1f); putVec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        putVec3(0.75f, 0.25f, 1f); putVec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        putVec3(0.50f, 0.75f, 1f); putVec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        buf.flip();

        // bind program
        GL30.glUseProgram(program);

        // bind vertex array
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        // upload graphics data and draw
        GL30.glBindBuffer(GL30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        GL30.glBufferData(GL30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf, GL30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL30.glDrawArrays(GL30.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        // reset vertex data buffer
        buf.clear();
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////

    static void putVec3(float x, float y, float z) {
        buf.putFloat(x);
        buf.putFloat(y);
        buf.putFloat(z);
    }

    static void putVec4(float x, float y, float z, float w) {
        buf.putFloat(x);
        buf.putFloat(y);
        buf.putFloat(z);
        buf.putFloat(w);
    }

}
```